# How to add and remove line from notepad file using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Need code to add and remove lines from notepad file using selenium in java. I have to do some more operations on notepad but add and remove will be helpful.

Comment: What do you really want is to simply interact with text file or you need indeed to interact with a desktop application?

Comment: Selenium can only automate a browser it cannot interact with a notepad file. You need to use other Classes and packages in java. what all have you tried, paste your code. Some amount of "Research"  is expected before you ask a question on this forum. Go through the [Help Secion](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working code.

**To add line in notepad or text file.**

**Step 1**: Read existing data from notepad in list.

```
public static List<String> readTextFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    // use BufferedReader to read notepad file line by line
    FileReader fReader = null;
    BufferedReader bfrReader = null;
    // Store lines in a
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    File fp = new File(filePath);
    if (fp.exists()) {
        fReader = new FileReader(fp);
        bfrReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        String line = null;
        do {
            // Read one line and store it in String variable
            line = bfrReader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } while (line != null);
        bfrReader.close();
        fReader.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
    return lines;
}
```

**Step 2:** Add new line to the list, you want to append in java file.

Here we used above function to read existing file before appending new line.

```
public static void appendLine(String filePath, String line) throws IOException {
    // read old notepad file and store lines
    List<String> lines = readTextFile(filePath);
    // add new line to the list
    lines.add(line);
    FileWriter fWriter;
    BufferedWriter bWriter;
    File fp = new File(filePath);
    if (fp.exists()) {
        fWriter = new FileWriter(fp);
        bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        // write to notepad file
        for (String oneLine : lines) {
            bWriter.append(oneLine);
            bWriter.newLine();
        }
        bWriter.close();
        fWriter.close();

    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
}
```

**To replace string or Regrex**

```
    public static void replaceRegrex(File fSrc, String regrex, String strReplace) throws IOException {
    String fSrcStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(fSrc.toPath()));
    String fStr = fSrcStr.replaceAll(regrex, strReplace);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fSrc);
    fileWriter.write(fStr);
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

For more notepad related operation refer below links which contain code having more details.

1. [Java class for append operation](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/code-to-create-and-update-notepad-text-file/)
2. For other [java operations on text file](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/java-library-for-text-file-operations/) like appendLine, compareTextFiles, createTextFile, readTextFile, replaceRegrex, searchRegrex